# How to configure datacontrol to access secured webservice?

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

Can anyone please tell me how to configure datacontrol to access secured webservice ??

In my application I am doing the following steps,

1) Generating datacontrols directly by using secured webserive wsdl.

2) Dragged method(getEmployee(Object)) from datacontrol and dropped it in a UI(MethodExecution.amx).

3) Created another page(LoginPage.amx) for entering username and password.

4) When user enters detail in LoginPage.amx and click submit. These details needs to be injected into webservice request to invoke "Secured webservice" method(getEmployee(Object)) in "MethodExecution.amx".

I searched in Google and got only one link related to this, a link by andrejus "http://andrejusb.blogspot.be/2012/11/adf-mobile-secured-web-service-access.html", however from this example I am not understanding how they are injecting username/password into webservice request, What is the use of using `adfCredentialstore`??, Why do we need to use security policies??

Can anyone please tell me how can i implement this functionality(Invoking secured webservice method) in my mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a step by step video with the process here: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/accessing_secure_web_services_from

Note that the demo uses a "remote" login server, and you are describing a local login.